# How does youtube recommender train video_id embedding?

Tags: tensorflow, youtube, embedding

Youtube combines several videos and use average embedding, yet train the embedding.

From 3.2 of [Deep Neural Networks for YouTube Recommendations](https://storage.googleapis.com/pub-tools-public-publication-data/pdf/45530.pdf)

> The network requires fixed-sized dense inputs and simply averaging
>   the embeddings performed best among several strategies (sum,
>   component-wise max, etc.). Importantly, the embeddings are learned
>   jointly with all other model parameters through normal gradient
>   descent backpropagation updates.

How is it possible to train an embedding when you are inputting average of embeddings?

It's like chicken and egg problem. You need an embedding if you want to average embeddings for video, but then how can you have an embedding before you have trainning data (which is the average embedding)

[image]

Comment: actually, after asking it, I think I guess one could just randomly initialize embeddings and start from there.. averge the random embeddings, and backprop, and iterate..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioning the clarification in the Answer Section (even though it is present in the Comment's section by eugene), for the benefit of the community.

> Youtube Recommender may train video_id embedding by just Randomly
>   Initializing Embeddings and start from there.. average the Random
>   Embeddings, and Back propagate, and Iterate.